# Shadow is not working on the textview. How to fix it?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, glow

I have tried so many times and also try every method to glow a text.
but it's not working.

See in the Image.[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#05090B"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:textColor="#16C61F"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="41dp"
        android:text="INAM"
       android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:padding="15dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please insert the code you have tried instead of sending an image of it.

Comment: Now i have done to add a code. can you solve this now?

Answer (score 0):

Please use 41sp not 41dp that way you will not get errors

Comment: A reference to some doc to back your answer will help OP tremendously.

Comment: Actually i want to glow my textview.